# How can 1+1=3 be possible?

Tags: education

I've been looking at some proofs but none make any sense to me, can someone prove this is true?

One of them...
Suppose $a=b$

$$ \Rightarrow a=b $$

Multiply each side by $b$

$$ \Rightarrow ab=b^2 $$

Subtract a^2 from each side

$$ \Rightarrow ab-a^2=b^2-a^2 $$

Simplify
$$ \Rightarrow a=a+b $$
$$ \Rightarrow a+1=a+b+1 $$

Because a=b
$$ \Rightarrow a+1=2a+1 $$

Suppose a=1
$$ \Rightarrow 1+1=2+1 $$

NOTE: I'm a 10th grader

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE! Can you show us the proof you're looking at? There are a lot of false proofs of this sort out there, typically involving division by 0, I would imagine that's probably the gimmick in the proof you've found. Here's a [helpful link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to get a sense for how to use MathJax.

Comment: @AmaanM there it is!

Comment: The step from ${ab-a^2 = b^2-a^2}$, you are factoring both sides as ${a(b-a)=(a+b)(a-b)}$ - note it is invalid to cancel ${(a-b)}$, since ${a=b\Rightarrow a-b=0}$. You are dividing by $0$ here

Comment: Provocative title.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Answer (score 2):

OK. Let's walk through this, somewhat more nicely formatted:

Suppose $a=b$. Then
\begin{align}
a&=b \tag{1}
\end{align}
Multiply each side by $b^2$
\begin{align}
 ab&=b^2
\tag{2}
\end{align}

Subtract $a^2$ from each side
\begin{align}
ab-a^2& =b^2-a^2 \tag{3}
\end{align}

Simplify
\begin{align}
a&=a+b  \tag{4}\\
a+1&=a+b+1  \tag{5}
\end{align}
Because $a=b$
\begin{align}
a+1=2a+1  \tag{6}
\end{align}

Suppose $a=1$
\begin{align}
1+1&=2+1  \tag{7}
\end{align}

Where to begin? Well, right at the start, I think you're saying "Let $a$ be any real number, and let $b = a$." So let me just run with that, writing notes to the right explaining each step:

\begin{align}
a & = b & \text{by assumption} \tag{1} \\
ab & = b^2 & \text{multiply both sides by $b$} \tag{2} \\
ab-a^2 & = b^2 -a ^2 & \text{subtract $a^2$ from both sides} \tag{3} \\
a(b-a) & = (b+a)(b-a)& \text{factoring, difference of squares} \tag{4} \\
a & = (b+a)& \text{Divide through by $b-a$} \tag{5} \\
a+1 & = b+a + 1& \text{Add 1 to each side} \tag{6} \\
a+1 & = a+a + 1& \text{Replace $b$ by $a$ using Eq. 1} \tag{7} \\
1+1 & = 1+1 + 1& \text{Because $a$ was arbitrary,}\\
& & \text{we can apply equation 7 to $a = 1$} \tag{8} \\
2 & = 3& \text{Simplification} \tag{8} \\
\end{align}

So that's the "proof". The failure is at step 5, where you say that $pq = pr$ implies that $q = r$; that's true only if you know $p$ is nonzero. For instance $0 \cdot 5 = 0 \cdot 7$, but that doesn't let you conclude that $5 = 7$, because $0$ has no multiplicative inverse. In your case, the number $b-a$ is playing the role of $p$, and because $b$ and $a$ are the same, you're really "dividing through by $0$", and that's the error.